# How to encode Cyrillic and Latin characters in one dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, character-encoding, cyrillic

Cyrillic and Latin characters in one data frame won't show when I use the following code

`..., encoding='utf-8')`

this is what I get for the cyrillic

`<U+0415><U+043B><U+044C><U+0441><U+043A>`

The Latin characters are fine.

How can I encode both languages in one data frame?

Comment: How/where exactly are you looking at that data?

Comment: I use it in Jupyter (Python 3) and also tried it with R with Rstudio